# How can I load environment variables into docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to pass arguments into my local docker-compose.yml file through a configuration file. My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:

    app:
        build:
            context: .
        image: {$WEB_DOMAIN_NAME}/app
        ...
```

My `.env` looks like this:

```
server.conf
```

My `server.conf` looks like this:

```
WEB_DOMAIN_NAME = example.co.uk
```

However, when I try to run `docker-compose up -d` I get this error

> ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
> in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 9
> expected , but found ''
> in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 8, column 34

How can I load my `server.conf` into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you copy the contents of `server.conf` to `.env`. It can be manually or through script.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue! I'll mark it when I can. I also flipped `{$}` to `${}` after re-reading the documentation